# Route to controller to subfolder in Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, routes

I am a beginner in Laravel and I have a specific question and I hope you can send in the right direction.
I have read and tryed a lot of solutions written in this forum with no success.

Oke lets start.

1. I want to change my **www.domain.com/support** to subdirectory **www.domain.com/support/support**
2. Created **app-->Http-->Support-->SupportController.php** and added:

   `namespace app\Http\Controllers\Support; 
       use app\Http\Controllers;
                   /**
                      * Display the Help Center.
                      *
                      * @return Response
                      */
                     public function support()
                     {
                         return view('static.support');
                     }`
3. Added in the **app-->Http-->routes.php**

   `Route::group(['domain' => env('APP_DOMAIN', 'domain.com'),
       ], function () {
           require 'Routes/general.php';   });`
4. Added in the **app-->Http-->routes-->general.php**

   `Route::get('/support', ['as' => 'static.support', 'uses' =>'Support\SupportController@support']);`
5. Added the **support.blade.php** in the following folder **Resources-->views-->static-->support**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Controller namespace has nothing to do with URLs. If you want to use `http://www.domain.com/support/support`, just use this route:

```
Route::get('support/support', 'SupportController@support');
```

Comment: This was the first option I tryed and then I received an Error 500. Just tested it again..not working Error 500. Must I also change this value  `=> 'static.support'`?

Comment: You should look what exactly error do you get. You can find error messages in `/storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: I have solved the problem. I have added the `'support/support'` and I have added a extra support to the return view. `return view('static.support.support');` Works like a charm! 

Everyone, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Support; 

use App\Http\Controllers;

class SupportController extends Controller
{
    public function support()
    {
        return view('static.support');
    }
}
```

Please confirm your controller looks like my example above rather than the controller example in your question.

Also, please provide errors from your `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: I am using homestead for development and the storage/logs/ is empty no laravel.log file. Does Homestead store the logfile somewhere else?